# check if various elements have class

Tags: jquery

I need to check that all elements have a certain class, if they all have the class then I need to perform something:
I think the following just checks one element:

```
   <div class="game-area">  
        <div class="position1 block position"></div>
        <div class="position2 block position"></div>
        <div class="position3 block position"></div>
        <div class="position4 block position"></div>
        <div class="position5 block position"></div>
        <div class="position6 block position"></div>
    </div>

if ( $(".position").hasClass("removed") ) {
 ....)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, then you can do this:

```
if($('.position').filter(".removed").length == $('.position').length){
    // do something
}
```

You can remove the filter if you want and use it as a single selector `$('.position.remove');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
  $('.position').each(function(obj){
      if($(obj).hasClass('removed')){
               //Do you stuff
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var positionElems = $(".position");
var positionWithRemoved = $(".position.removed");
```

And then check the length:

```
if (positionElems.length == positionWithRemoved.length) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements of .game-area in this case:

```
$('.game-area').children('div').each(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'removed' ) ){ // Do something }
});
```

This will check every element that is a child of game.area

Optionally:

```
$('.game-area').children('div.position').each(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'removed' ) ){ // Do something }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.not` and check if there's remaining element :

```
if(!$('.position').not('.removed').length){
    //all elements has `.removed`
}
```